# Add path to join the node D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to add path between two nodes on mouse down and pn mouse up i get the both nodes but when i try to add link(path )i can't draw it

```
  var addPath = function(){
        var obj = {};
        obj.source = source;
        obj.target = target;

        NodePanData.connections.push(obj);
        source = undefined;
        target = undefined;
    }

 var inputs = gStates.selectAll('.extraCircle')
            .data(function(d){
            if(d.inputList){
                var r = radius+15;
                var a = getStartingPoint(d.inputList.length,true);
                for(t in d.inputList){
                    d.inputList[t].x = r*Math.sin(a);
                    d.inputList[t].y = r*Math.cos(a);
                    a = a + 0.45;
                }
                return d.inputList;
            }
            return [];
        }).enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr({
                "transform": function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")";
                },
                'class': 'extraCircle'
            }).on("mousedown", function (d) {
                isLinkDraw =true;
                target = d;
                console.log("mousedoun"+ d.id)
            }) .on("mouseup", function (d) {
                    isLinkDraw =false;
                    target = d;
                    addPath();

                    console.log("mouseUp"+ d.id);
                });




    var output = gStates.selectAll('.outPuts')
        .data(function(d){
            if(d.outputList){
                var r = radius+15;
                var a = getStartingPoint(d.outputList.length,false);
                for(t in d.outputList){
                    d.outputList[t].x = r*Math.sin(a);
                    d.outputList[t].y = r*Math.cos(a);
                    a = a + 0.45;
                }
                return d.outputList;
            }
            return [];
        }).enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr({
            "transform": function (d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")";
            },
            'class': 'outPuts'
        }).on("mousedown", function (d) {
            isLinkDraw =true;
            source = d;
            console.log("mousedoun")
        }) .on("mouseup", function (d) {
            isLinkDraw =false;
            source = d;
            addPath();
            console.log("mouseUp")
        });
```

here my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmeetRana/DNXTS/8/)

Comment: What's the question? I don't see anything in your code that tries to draw a line on mouse down.

Comment: addPath() at Line:360 push a object to list

Comment: path is between small nodes not the big one

Comment: Ok, so after adding the node to the list you need to run the code that takes that data and draws circles accordingly again.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AmeetRana/DNXTS/7/ i update it after adding path but don't know why path is draw some where else

Comment: @LarsKotthoff  mouse down on "Genome2" drag to "Reference Genome Out 3" will draw the path at top of svg

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043)? It shows how to create nodes and links by dragging and dropping.

Comment: ya i try it it's not helping me

Comment: here i am connecting child node not the root nodes may be this can be issue

Comment: You have several hundred lines of code, so it's hard to see what's going on. Could you maybe narrow it down to a minimal example?

Comment: i mark code where i am trying to draw paths u can starts with end on file http://jsfiddle.net/AmeetRana/DNXTS/8/   i clean some code also